# running cron.php thows a "maximum execution time exceeded" fatal error

Tags: php, drupal, cron

I am using Drupal 6.19 with quite a lot modules. Since I added another domain using Domain Access, added a panel variant and a node type, the cron first exhausted the memory limit of 512MB. I increased this limit to 1024MB. After I have done that, the "Maximum execution time" of 240 seconds is being exceeded.

Any ideas? What additional information shpould I give?

Thanks

Lukas

Comment: Holycrap your cron requires a GIGABYTE of memory? That's sick!! Even for Drupal standards, that's a lot =)

Comment: Yes, it`s insane. I use some modules that really make me think that they should be rewritten...

Comment: How is the speed for the rest of the website? 4 minutes for every page load? =) Drupal requires a lot of memory for caching. If that's only necessary for the cronjob (every 4 hours?) it's doable if the rest of the website needs only a few MB.

Comment: Average load time is 1s. I make heavy use of caching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to look for croon implementations in your modules. Disable each of these (separately) temporarily too see if it makes any difference.

Maybe a module is running in some kind of loop. A possible candidate would be search.module, that lodas all comments of a single node. If you have nodes with thousands of comments (forum posts), that could be causing this.

Comment: I agree. Be careful to the display of content type with node relationships.

Comment: I had to disable search.module and update_status.module. After that I removed a view I just added before encountering that error and added it again. Now it works.

Comment: Yeah, I assume it's a node with many comments then, that is a typical issue. You can get the nodes with the most comments with the following query: `SELECT nid, COUNT(*) FROM comments GROUP BY nid ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC lIMIT 10`.

Answer (score 1):

Look inside: includes/common.inc
Line: 2716

Change the set_time_limit to a higher number such as 400.

Hope it will help someone.

Finau

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. It seems no matter what I did this one line was resetting my max timeout to 240. Thanks for that!!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to raise the max execution time with `set_time_limit()` but I think it would be good to find out what your script is doing for four minutes!

I don't know much about this drupal script but would suggest the following:

- Keep an eye on the database while it's running, I'm guessing that slow MySQL queries are likely to be the primary cause of it running slow
- If slow queries aren't the cause setup some kind of profiling (would recommend xdebug + webgrind for something simple), set_time_limit() to something really high and run the script. Use the profiling data to see what's so slow and then work to optimise it.